# Understanding the difference between a divisor and a factor

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, terminology

Consider an arbitrary polynomial of degree four
$$ P(x)=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e,$$
where $a,b,c,d,e\in\mathbb{R}$. If $P(x)$ is divisible by a quadratic, say $(x-1)(x+9)$, are $x-1$ and $x+9$ factors of $P(x)$? Hence the factor theorem could be used to find $d$ and $e$ of $P(x)$ if $a,b$ and $c$ are known, since
\begin{align}
P(1)&=x+e=\alpha \\
P(-9)&=-9x+e=\beta \\
\end{align}
for $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You can also apply polynomial long division to reduce the degree. Since the remaining polynomial has degree $2$, you can find further solutions (if they exist) with the well known formula.

Comment: @Peter Thanks. To avoid doing long division (not that there's anything wrong with it), is my logic correct? I figured that, for example, if $16$ is divisible by $4$ then $4$ must also be a factor of $16$. I am not entirely convinced the same logic applies with polynomials.

Comment: You can also use Vieta's rule. But I do not understand how you get $P(1)=x+e$. We have $P(1)=a+b+c+d+e$ , your $P(1)$ even depends on $x$ , but this must be a fixed value. Do you mean another "$x$" here ?

Comment: @Peter All constant values are absorbed by $\alpha$ on the RHS. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Not clear what you mean. However, since $(x-1)(x+9)$ is a divisor of $P(x)$ , we know $P(1)=P(-9)=0$. If you know $a,b,c$ , you get two equations for $d,e$ which you can solve. Maybe this is what you mean.